# How to convert a u32 constant to i32 constant without unsafe in Rust?

Tags: rust, constants

I'm trying to define a new i32 constant from an existing u32 constant, for use in a match expression as io::Error::raw_os_error() returns an i32, but winapi error constants are u32.

In the code example below, the existing u32 constant would be `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`.

The only way I've found to do that is using a unsafe block.

I'm new to Rust, so is there a way do to convert a u32 to i32 constant without unsafe?

```rust
use std::io::Error;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

const ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES: u32 = 18; // defined in winapi winerror
const ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES_I32: i32 = unsafe { ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES as i32 };
// Attempted to use safe conversion does not compile:
// error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
// const ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES_I32: i32 = i32::try_from(ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES).unwrap();

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let err = Error::last_os_error();
    match err.raw_os_error() { // an i32
        Some(ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES_I32)  => { println!("No more files..."); },
        Some(_) => return Err(err),
        _  => {}
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: The `unsafe` block you have there is already not needed. Rust even tells you that when you compile. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57c411edba9b7c4c1af8a91d49dda0d8

Answer (score 2):

As @loganfsmyth pointed out, I don't need the unsafe in that case. I'm not sure how I managed to miss the warning (probably should stop coding so late)...

This compiles just fine:

```rust
const ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES: u32 = 18; // defined in winapi winerror
const ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES_I32: i32 = ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES as i32;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES_I32);
}
```